# R, Caret, train(), predict(), GBM, Error: Error in model.frame.default(..): Factor has new levels

Tags: r, r-caret, gbm

So I have a pretty good idea of what is happening but I'm wondering how to handle the error, I've seen other posts similar to this but they were not specific to Gradient Boosting Machine models.  They all seem to be related to GLMs and the error isn't being caused by the same thing I don't think.

Here's my code:

```
myTuneGrid <- expand.grid(n.trees=c(100,200), interaction.depth=c(9,10,11,12), shrinkage=0.1, n.minobsinnode=10)

fitControl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number =5,verboseIter = FALSE,returnResamp = "all")

myModel <- train(as.factor(target) ~ .,data = trainingDataC.GB, method = "gbm",trControl = fitControl,tuneGrid = myTuneGrid)

myPrediction <- predict(myModel,newdata=testDataC)
```

Here's my error:

> Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action,
>   xlev = object$xlevels) :    factor 47V has new levels E, H, J

So my factor variable has a bunch of levels in my training set, but from the error I'm guessing not all levels are represented in my training set.  When I go to my test set there are new levels that were not in my training set so I'm getting this error?

This is a supervised learning problem, I can't change the test set and move data to the training set. So it's not a sampling problem.

Anyway, does anyone know any settings or quick fixes so that this doesn't cause my program to crash?

Comment: hard to help if you don't provide no data

Comment: There is no "quick fix." You have to decide how you want to do out of sample prediction. And most code bases don't allow for this by default, so you'll likely have to write a custom predict function... I'm not sure about gbm.

Comment: So you just want to recover on error? Look at the `tryCatch` function. If you need recommendations for methods that might be more appropriate for your data, you can ask at [stats.se].

Comment: Sorry everyone, my data is just the most recent kaggle.  CARDIF doesn't seem relevant i don't know what any of the V'S mean. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This happens quite a bit on kaggle competitions. You can combine the variables to create a levels argument to make sure the factor contains all the levels in both train and test. You see this all quite a lot in the kaggle scripts.

See this very simple example based on mtcars. You just need to fill in the variable name in quotes (e.g. "cyl") and the variable will be set to a factor in both the train and test set with all the levels available in both sets. This will just prevent your model from giving an error. This does not mean that it will learn anything from the factor levels not available in the training set.

```
train <- subset(mtcars, cyl < 8)
test <- subset(mtcars, cyl >= 8)


fact_train_test <- function(x) {
  levels <- unique(c(train[[x]], test[[x]]))
  train[[x]] <<- factor(train[[x]], levels=levels)
  test[[x]]  <<- factor(test[[x]],  levels=levels)
}

fact_train_test("cyl")
```

There are probably other methods of doing this, but it works.